# How does the metamagnetic transition occur?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

How does applying a critically strong magnetic field to an antiferromagnetic material cause it to become ferromagnetic?
What role does the magnetocrystalline anisotropy of the material play in this process?
How does a critically strong external magnetic fields cause the material to change from antiferromagnetic to ferromagnetic?

Answer (score 0):

Recallthat in magnetic systems you have three quantities at play: magnetic field, coupling of spins (i.e. tendency to align) and thermal energy.

Let $\vec{H}$ be the applied magnetic field, and consider only first neighbor interactions between the spins $\vec{S}_i$. The Hamiltonian of the system is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}=-\sum_{(i,j)} J_{ij} \vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{S}_j - h \sum_i \vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{H}
\end{equation}
As always there is a competition between the minimisation of the Hamiltonian (resulting in a parallel alignment if ferromagnetic, or anti-parallel if antiferromagnetic), and thermal fluctuations of order $k_B T$.

Consider an antiferromagnet ($J_{ij}<0$). At zero field ($H=0$), the spins want to align anti-parallel. However if the field is really strong, the second term of the Hamiltonian is dominant:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}\approx - h \sum_i \vec{S}_i \cdot \vec{H}
\end{equation}
and the configuration that minimises the Hamiltonian is that of full alignment. This corresponds to ferromagnetism.
Of course that at weak fields, the alignment is determined by the first term of the Hamiltonian, and antiferromagnetism is the dominant effect.

As for anisotropies: notice that in the above Hamiltonian there is an assumption of isotropy, since $J$ and $h$ are the same for all directions of space. Otherwise you would have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}=-\sum_{(i,j)} (J^x_{ij} S^x_i S^x_j+J^y_{ij} S^y_i S^y_j+J^z_{ij} S^z_i S^z_j) -  \sum_i( h_x S^x_i H_x +h_y S^y_i H_z+h_z S^z_i H_z)
\end{equation}